# local settings of Django 1.6.1 is not applied when i sync with database

Tags: python, django, settings

I was able to see properly through the shell that the local setting has been applied correctly. However, I was able to see not being applied properly when it is in synchronization with the database, the error occurs.

Here is the main `settings.py` :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'kidsmamma',
        'USER': 'kidsmamma',
        'PASSWORD': 'kidsmamma@pass!@#$',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
        'TEST_COLLATION': 'utf8_unicode_ci'
    }
}

. . .

# LOCAL SETTING
try:
    from local_settings import *
    print DATABASES
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Here is the `local_settings.py` :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'test_kidsmamma',
        'USER': 'test',
        'PASSWORD': 'test@pass!@#$',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
        'TEST_COLLATION': 'utf8_unicode_ci'
    }
}
```

When i run `./manage.py shell` :

```
(kidsmamma)[09:04 오후 kidsmamma@dev-server ~/kidsmamma]$ ./manage.py shell
{'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 'NAME': 'test_kidsmamma', 'test_COLLATION': 'utf8_unicode_ci', 'HOST': '', 'USER': 'test', 'PASSWORD': 'test@pass!@#$', 'PORT': ''}}
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:03:06) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> 
KeyboardInterrupt
>>>
```

And after excute `./manage.py syncdb`, the error occur like this:

```
(kidsmamma)[09:04 오후 kidsmamma@dev-server ~/kidsmamma]$ ./manage.py syncdb
{'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 'NAME': 'test_kidsmamma', 'test_COLLATION': 'utf8_unicode_ci', 'HOST': '', 'USER': 'test', 'PASSWORD': 'test@pass!@#$', 'PORT': ''}}
Syncing...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/kidsmamma/.virtualenvs/kidsmamma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/home/kidsmamma/.virtualenvs/kidsmamma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/kidsmamma/.virtualenvs/kidsmamma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/kidsmamma/.virtualenvs/kidsmamma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/kidsmamma/.virtualenvs/kidsmamma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 415, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/home/kidsmamma/.virtualenvs/kidsmamma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 89, in handle_noargs
    db.connection_init() 
  File "/home/kidsmamma/.virtualenvs/kidsmamma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/db/mysql.py", line 183, in connection_init
    cursor = self._get_connection().cursor()
  File "/home/kidsmamma/.virtualenvs/kidsmamma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 157, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/home/kidsmamma/.virtualenvs/kidsmamma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 129, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home/kidsmamma/.virtualenvs/kidsmamma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 124, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/kidsmamma/.virtualenvs/kidsmamma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/kidsmamma/.virtualenvs/kidsmamma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 124, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/kidsmamma/.virtualenvs/kidsmamma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 112, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/kidsmamma/.virtualenvs/kidsmamma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 435, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/kidsmamma/.virtualenvs/kidsmamma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kidsmamma/.virtualenvs/kidsmamma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 193, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'kidsmamma'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

If i want to connect to a database without the local setting, there is no problem, but what happens when i have imported the local setting, I can't find the cause.

I'm using django version 1.6.1.
If you need more information, please leave a comment.
I hope you can help me!

Comment: In `./manage.py shell`, this commands work? `from django.db import connection` and then `cursor = connection.cursor()`

Comment: I can't directly see your problem -- although I suspect it may have todo with the fact your test database does not already exist? But if I can make a suggestion -- it seems to me your trying to create a test database? If this the case, you should skip the entire effort, and take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/. Using Django's built in test system will make your life infinitely simpler.

Answer (score 0):

First connect to MySQL Server from MySQL client command line:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```

Enter your `root` password for `root` user of your  MySQL Server, the command line prompt should be change to:

```
mysql>
```

Now try to list all current databases with:

```
mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
```

And try to list all users of mysql by:

```
mysql> SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user;
```

Now consider the output of them, and according to `DATABASES` settings of `local_settings.py`, if your  `test` user doesn't exist, create it with your password:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'test@pass!@#$';
```

And if your `test_kidsmamma` database doesn't exist, create it:

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE test_kidsmamma  CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

And then grant all privileges of `test_kidsmamma` database to `test` user:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL ON test_kidsmamma.* TO 'test'@'%';
```

Ok, now you can try `python manage.py syncdb` again.

Note that you can also try it for `DATABASES` settings in `settings.py`

Comment: Thank about your reply. But i made database and granted all database's permissions to user `test_kidsmamma` before run `./manage.py syncdb`.

Comment: You must set permissions to `test` user, because you set `'USER': 'test'` in `DATABASES` settings of `local_settings.py` file. review my answer.